# Error in the dates(Year) of the previous refusal

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

I applied for a UK visit visa and had disclosed my previous refusal, However, I accidentally mentioned the wrong year(2021 instead of 2022) but the correct Month, I also enclosed the refusal letter and a copy of the email I received for the refusal that contains the application number too. I had already done my biometrics.

I want to know if this is a significant mistake or something that can be done or if should I just leave it as it is cause there is little I can do now.

Comment: You could withdraw the application. However a refund may not be possible. I don’t think there is much to worry - as you have disclosed it (Good!) and even included the email/letter - which will have correct dates on.

Comment: also in the email copy I sent, the application number of the refused applicaion is also mentioned, I even mentioned the correct  month, however I don't know why I accidentally typed 2021 instead of 2022.

Comment: It happens. I applied for a UK visa last month and mistyped the month but correct year when telling them how long I would stay. It was approved. If your application is solid - this mistake shouldn’t be an issue at all. I wouldn’t worry.

Comment: ok thank you, I believe I can sleep now, just keeping my fingers crossed though... no matter how many times I made sure that each part of the application is correct, I still made a mistake... I even explained each and every transaction, even property/stocks paper I attached, all the other dates of transactions I mentioned are correct... explained everything. I don't how I missed that... if it was a test I wouldn't worry about a silly mistake but this time I really am worried.